# How can I generate random ActiveRecord entry without redundancy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What's the best practice for returning random records without redundancy?

For example, if I want to build something like Stumbleupon, the user wouldn't expect to land on the same page already visited before.

Big picture I guess I could store all the visit history and make sure the algorithm excludes those records when randomizing, but I am curious about the details. Or if there's a better way...

Comment: Your could use [Array#sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample), which performs sampling without replacement (no dups). If you wish to return `m` of  `n` records, return those at offsets `(0...n).to_a.sample(m)`. For example, if `n=20; m=5`, return the records at offsets `[14, 18, 0, 11, 12]`. I don't know Rails, but presume there is a way to extract records by their offsets into the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
ModelName.limit(10).order("RANDOM()")
```

Comment: Thanks, but that would only ensure no redundancy up to 10 records, no?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to record the visits, here I use the field visited in perhaps a date field ?

```
rand_record = Model.where(visited: nil).order("RANDOM()").first
```